# htaccess 301 rule doesn't redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I just can't seem to figure out how to 301 redirect an old URL `https://www.mydomain.com/old_url/` to `https://www.mydomain.com/new_url/`

I currently have the following in my htaccess (note the second rule related to this issue):

```
RewriteEngine On
# SSL redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /old_url/
RewriteRule ^/old_url$ https://www.mydomain.com/new_url [R=301,nc]

# If the root has a querystring with at least 1 character
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.mydomain.com/new_home_page [R=301,nc]
```

I'm also using Django if that makes a difference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /old_url/
RewriteRule ^/old_url$ https://www.mydomain.com/new_url [R=301,nc]
```

You may try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} old_url/(.*)
RewriteRule .* https://www.mydomain.com/new_url/%1 [R=301,QSA,NC]
```

Will redirect:

`https://www.mydomain.com/old_url/whatever`

To:

`https://www.mydomain.com/new_url/whatever`

**UPDATED**

If the rest of the URI ("whatever") is not to be copied, use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} old_url.*
RewriteRule .* https://www.mydomain.com/new_url [R=301,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: That seems to do what you say it will. However, I don't care about the `whatever` part.

Comment: I went with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} old_url/
RewriteRule ^/$ https://www.mydomain.com/new_url/ [R=301,QSA,NC]
`

Comment: Well, I added just in case but it doesn't affect the rule when there is nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the update. One thing I'd like to do is restrict the match to `old_url` or `old_url/` - is that possible? Right now, I can type in anything after `old_url` but I don't want this to run into potential conflicts with other URLs in the future.

Comment: Yes, but be aware that any trailing space will cause the condition to fail. Just change the condition, like this: `old_url/?$`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work just fine:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old_url$ /new_url [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^old_url/(.*) /new_url/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything either. I still get a 404 when I visit the old URL.

Comment: @AbidA Did you place the `.htaccess` in the root of your webserver? Try with my update (you might not have these options set as default).

Comment: The file is in the right place as the other rules work just fine. I tried your update and same 404.

Comment: @AbidA Just to make sure that it's loading the `.htaccess` file, try to type some bogus in there (such as `RiwroteOngine Of`, or a simple `akljdlad`), to see if you then get a `500` like you should.